# how to get multiple values when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, struts2

I'm trying to include checkbox with the list.Using that code I've included checkbox successfully.But I can not get the multiple values by using that.If I checked three checboxes, I can get only one value from that list. please help me out to find out the reason why I can not get multiple values at the same time.

```
 <div class="profile-input"  style="height:100px; width:200px; overflow:auto;">

                 <s:iterator value="cityList">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cityNumber[]" id="cityNo"  value="<s:property value="cityId"/>" onchange="getcountrycode(false);" multiple="multiple"/><s:property value="cityName"/><br/>
                    </s:iterator>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you have a Collection waiting on the Action, you need to point the index of each element by using `IteratorStatus`; 
also include city name in a label, generate univoque IDs, and remove `multiple="multiple"` that doesn't mean anything on checkboxes:

```
<s:iterator value="cityList" stat="ctr">
    <input type = "checkbox" 
           name = "cityNumber[<s:property value="%{#ctr.index}"/>]" 
          value = "<s:property value="cityId"/>" 
             id = "cityNo<s:property value="%{#ctr.index}"/>"
    />

    <label for = "cityNo<s:property value="%{#ctr.index}"/>">
       <s:property value="cityName"/>
    </label>

    <br/>
</s:iterator>
```

Then, it would be better to use Struts UI tag `<s:checkbox />` :

```
<s:iterator value="cityList" stat="ctr">
    <s:checkbox name = "cityNumber[%{#ctr.index}]" 
          fieldValue = "cityId" 
               label = "cityName"
    />
    <br/>
</s:iterator>
```

Or even removing the iterator by using `<s:checkboxlist/>` [like explained here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery map/get functions:

```
$('#save_value').click(function () {
    var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function (_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
    }).get();

    alert(sel);
});
```

See demo here.. http://jsfiddle.net/J3LNt/2/

Comment: This applies to all the checkboxes that are in the pages scope.